# Vaadin8 grid with List<~> in property

Tags: vaadin-grid, vaadin8

I am trying to create a grid using Vaadin and having trouble in showing data which is inside the data source. The Datasource definition is like below

```
public class Customer {

private String name;
private List<Contacts> contacts;
}

public class Contacts {

private String phonecontact;
private String emailcontact;
}
```

Now when I write the code to show data using Vaadin

```
  private Grid<Customer> grid=new Grid<>(Customer.class);
  grid.setItems(createCutromers());

   ...............
   ..............
  private List<Customer> createCutromers(){

    List<Customer> customerList=new ArrayList<>();

    Customer cust=new Customer();
    cust.setName("Rocky");
    Contacts cont=new Contacts();
    List<Contacts> contactsList=new ArrayList();
    cont.setEmailcontact("wwww");cont.setPhonecontact("212");
    contactsList.add(cont);
    cust.setContacts(contactsList);
    customerList.add(cust);
     return customerList;
   }
```

Now I am trying to show Name and contacts in Grid , how should I go about it? The issue is List is shown as Object. What could be the easiest way to do it.

The output should be like

```
name   |   phonecontact   | emailcontacts
-----------------------------------------
Rocky  |    212           | www
```

Comment: If you add `Grid` columns manually, you have full control over the content. Is that an option?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich is right (eg: [generated columns doc](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.generatedcolumns)). Nonetheless, you'll have to consider how many contacts a customer can have, for example a customer may have 2, but another one may have 100 making it difficult to display it nicely. Perhaps you could consider showing the number of contacts in that cell, with a _View_ button that opens a popup or takes you to a different view with a grid that displays the list of contacts for the selected customer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Lets say if we know the number of contacts. will this be possible to achieve?

Comment: If you have the same number of contacts for all customers, you could generate columns accordingly. Click the [link](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.generatedcolumns) in my previous answer to see how. P.S. when replying to someone's comment you can use @username so they get a notification.